# How can I use Spring boot beans with liquidbase CustomTaskChange

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I have spring boot application.
I would like to implements liquidbase  CustomTaskChange in order to run some code.
However I couldn't find a way for using my existing spring beans or fetching them via applicationContext.

How can use spring beans with CustomTaskChange ?

Comment: @xerx593 thanks. Using Option1 or 2 didn't work `CustomTaskChange.execute` is being triggered before the application context is ready.
Singleton can work. I tried creating a  Singleton which implement `implements ApplicationContextAware` but it is called after  `CustomTaskChange.execute`

Comment: Then you name it, how can you " find a way for using my existing spring beans or fetching them via applicationContext"? .. *before* application context!

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds to me like your issue is actually that Liquibase is running a CustomTaskChange before all of your beans are first setup ?

First off, you can use ApplicationContextAware to fetch beans by implementing either of the following methods as your own:

```
// Fetches based on Class only
<T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType) throws BeanException;

// Fetches based on Class & Bean name (useful when you have multiple beans of same type)
<T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> requiredType) throws BeanException;
```

Second, you can use other spring annotations to control runtime.

`@DependsOn("liquibase")` is a common one but, there others such as `@Order`, `@Lazy`, etc. If you showed more of your code I might be able to assist further.